# add a comment on a line above a searched line in shell script

Tags: regex, shell, sed

Suppose below is a text file

```
abcd
abc:
```

I want to search for `abc:` and add `#` in front of `abcd`

OUTPUT

```
#abcd
abc:
```

I tried using

```
sed -e '/abc/ s/^#*/#/' -i file
```

but unable to do the above action.

Comment: And what if your file contains two consecutive `abc:`? Do you want to comment the first one? If yes, do you want to comment the line before it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are editing in-place, you can use `ed`:

```
printf '%s\n' '/abc:/-1 s/^/#/' w q | ed -s file
```

With POSIX `sed` it is more tricky. One possibility is:

```
sed -i '
    N
    /abc:/ {
        s/^/#/
        :a
        n
        ba
    }
    P
    D
' file
```

Both scripts assume that `abc:` cannot appear on the first line of the file, and that you wish to change only the line above the first occurrence of the pattern even if it appears multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

A `tac | awk + tac` solution:

```bash
tac file | awk 'p {$0 = "#" $0} {p = (/^abc:/ ? 1 : 0)} 1'  | tac

#abcd
abc:
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GNU `sed`, you can use `-z` option to parse whole file at once and not line-by-line.

You final command would look something like this:

```
sed -zE 's/[^\n]*\nabc:/#\0/g' file
```

Here `[\n]*\nabc:` matches anything, newline and `abc:` and replaces it with `#` and previously matched data. `\0` in replacement string means full match of regex.

Comment: It outputs 
abc#d
abc:

However I need 
#abcd
abc:

Comment: @enghyd1, it shouldn't. Look at this [demo](https://ideone.com/p7TR59)

Comment: @enghyd1 your input file probably contains DOS line endings, see [why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` (tested with GNU `sed` and the `sed` that comes with macOS):

```
sed -n '1{h;d;};/abc:/{x;s/^/#/;x;};{x;p;};${g;p;}' file
```

Explanations: `sed` manages two data buffers: the *hold space* and the *pattern space*. When a new line is read it is stored in the pattern space. The script uses both spaces.

- We use the `-n` option to suppress the automatic printing. We print explicitly with the `p` command.
- `1{h;d;}`: if the current line is the first (address `1`) we copy it to the hold space (`h`) and start a new cycle (`d`).
- `/abc:/{x;s/^/#/;x;}`: if a line (other than the first) matches `abc:` we swap hold and pattern spaces (`x`), prepend a `#` (`s/^/#/`) and swap again (`x`).
- `{x;p;}`: we swap hold and pattern spaces (`x`) and print (`p`).
- `${g;p;}`: after reading the last line (`$`) we copy the hold space to pattern space (`g`) and print (`p`).

Note: this is a bit more complicated than using the `-z` option but works even if your source file contains NUL characters, and avoids slurping the whole file in memory which can be an issue with large files.

Note: if your file contains consecutive lines matching `abc:` they will be commented too. Example:

```
#foo
#abc:
#abc:
abc:
bar
```

If this is what you want add the `-i` flag to edit in place.

Comment: `sed 'N; /\nabc:/s/^/#/; P; D'`

Comment: Excellent! And so simpler. You should make it an answer, I'd upvote twice if I could. Note: as the OP did not specify that the `abc:` string is at the beginning of a line we should maybe use `\n.*abc:` instead of `\nabc:`.

Comment: It's based on my existing answer but this code can be simpler because your answer makes different assumptions about what behaviour is desired. The question is unclear. An additional possiblity that I don't think any current answers support is that `abc:` on the first line should cause a new blank comment line to be prepended.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{print (/^abc:/ ? "#" : "") prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
#abcd
abc:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner, as in the following example:

```
# Prepare test input:
cat > infile <<EOF
abcd
abc:
abc:
efgh
ijhk
abc:
EOF

perl -i.bak -lne '$prev = $curr; $curr = $_; if ( $curr =~ m{^abc:} ) { $prev = "#$prev"; } if ( $. > 1 ) { print $prev; } if ( eof ) { print $curr; } ' infile

# Print the result:

cat infile
#abcd
#abc:
abc:
efgh
#ijhk
abc:
```

Note that the previous line is **always** commented if the current line starts with `abc:`.

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`$.` : Current input line number.
`eof` : Returns 1 (true) if the end of file is found.

**See also:**

- [`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
- [`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)
- [`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/.*\n.*abc:/#&/;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and if that line contains `abc:`, insert `#` before the first line. Then print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. This might comment a line containing `abc:` if that line is above another containing `abc:`.